# Should I upvote the question if the OP asks me to?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

I have answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286596/2194456)

In the comments the OP asked me to upvote his question:

> i got answer yet i vote up u also vote up question  - Johnson

However, I don't really feel like the question is worth an up vote.

Should I report this behavior or up vote the question or ignore the comment altogether?

Comment: Option #4: upvote as requested, except for changing the "up" part to "down".

Comment: @Raff The value of a question isn't determined by comments on the answers. Voting should be done solely by the quality of the question itself

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Should i upvote the question if questioned person asks me to upvote
>   his question

If that's the only reason you would upvote, is because the questioner asked you to, then No. However, if it's a good question that deserves an upvote and you would normally upvote it, but just forgot, then maybe yes. But maybe still no, since he shouldn't leave comments asking for upvotes.

> I dont really feel its worth of up voting it.

Then don't upvote it. You can vote however you want. It's yours and only your decision.

> Should i report or up vote or ignore.

Flag the comment as either too chatty or not constructive so it can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't upvote if the user asks you too, unless you feel as if the question deservers and upvote itself. As said in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323847/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-upvotes-in-a-question?cb=1) post, if they ask for an upvote, edit it out. If they decline the edit, flag the post for mod attention and *do not* start an edit war.

Comment: +1 for addressing editing and preventing edit wars.

Comment: this question is about asking for upvote in comments, edit is not the option in this case ("In the comments the OP asked me...")