# Is it okay to ask for upvotes in a question?

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette

As the title suggests, I faced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453627/navbar-error-inserting-values-before-submit) (now removed) where the OP asks to upvote his question itself. I had never seen anyone doing that till now. I [edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12479514) and removed the request and "thanks in advance". OP rejected my edit instantly. Question quality was poor too, but that's not what I am worried about.

I have seen people asking to upvote in answers, and I am aware that it is [considered as noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271815/1437261), but I'm not sure about questions. I went ahead and flagged it for moderator attention, which got approved later on.

My question is, what should I do if I face this kind of scenario? Should I edit / flag / leave the question alone and enjoy my beer, etc.?

Comment: This one poster's only other question also featured that line. It was annyoing enough to be [edited out instantly](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37452227/2), even though the editor did not care to repair a couple of other issues.

Comment: @RadLexus I noticed that as well, but I knew that the meta effect is gonna do the needful lol.

Comment: It isn't either/or. Editing and enjoying your beer are *not* mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I don't usually want to get drunk when I am doing serious things :p

Comment: Note that having that line is probably the single best way to attract downvotes, so you're doing the OP a favor by removing it.

Comment: @Servy I don't know, "Don't downvote this" is equally effective, if not more so.

Comment: If someone did that with me, I'd *downvote* them instead..

Comment: Wow even that account got nuked..?!

Comment: @TJ I guess OP did that himself. I kinda feel sad for asking the question now.

Comment: gimmah all teh repz!

Comment: @TJ there were two quite dubious edits on that question by the same person and that editor is currently suspended maybe a moderator found cause to suspect puppetry.

Comment: In my opinion it is just bad etiquette *or* a **triggering signal** to upvote circle club ;(

Answer (score 159, accepted):

No, asking for upvotes is not OK, and noise like that should be removed.

You did exactly what you should do:

1. Edit the question (and maybe leave a comment)
2. Flag for moderator attention if OP rejects / rollbacks the edit.

In general, don't get into an edit war with OP, even when you know you are acting according to community guidelines / consensus.

Comment: I edited the question and left a comment for the OP

Comment: thanks that is what I expected. :) @rene saw your edit. Thank you.

Comment: @SugatoSengupta  I would however recommend that you look other other things that could have been improved in the post e.g. changing i -> I, and adding a ? to "Can I prevent it" to turn it into a question.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I should have.. Agreed :)

Comment: Perfect, right down to the "edit war" point. Ensure the comment you leave (if you leave one) isn't snarky. If the OP undoes the edit, just flag and move on (perhaps leave another non-snarky comment), but nothing *constructive* will happen if you edit it out again.

Comment: In my case, I didn't even try. I did it for the community in the first place, but I am just a noob at the end of the day. So , I prefer to remain quite lol :p

Answer (score 7):

Asking for upvotes is perfectly OK.  You should not remove that important part of the OP's message.

Oh, and please give me upvotes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obvious, troll is obvious 

Comment: Oh yes, I did, indeed :) And since we're in meta section: isn't there a way to upvote several times?

Comment: Argghhh... must .... downvote ..... want to ..... upvote..... => Coffee.

Comment: Love the balance of votes on this

Comment: @Yakk Sorry -- I don't really use meta anymore and was confused between the SO Meta and the SE Meta.

Comment: Please upvote this comment.

Comment: lowkey one of the best answers on meta

Comment: I actually wanted to upvote this, but a score of +56/-55...? couldn't resist. Too perfect.

Comment: Heh, now that is just evil... No votes for you (up or down)! :P

Comment: +62/-62. This is amazing.

Comment: This is pure gold.... wanted to downvote, but then anyone taking this answer literally needs to look up sarcasm in dictionary... so upvote it is...

Comment: Post lacks grammar and spelling errors. -1

Comment: +73 -72.. lovin it lol!!

Comment: +74, -74 Perfect balance. I won't vote and disturb it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, now you can restore the balance...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Someone else already did! :-)

Comment: @Renan: ***Perfect.*** Comments can't be downvoted, so you don't risk the backlash. Well played, sir/madam.

Comment: *(The penny drops)* Ah, people are doing it on purpose. *Slow Teej, slow!*

Comment: I balanced this answer when this was -8 vs +7 if I remember correctly, and thought it'd be cool if people kept it balanced. Good job people!

Comment: Ok, it's been 2 days.  Enough of the noise.  This answer is completely wrong (on purpose) and basically is a bullshit answer.  There are so many more upvotes than this post deserves and is misleading to new users.  This answer is not Anikan Skywalker and is not intended to bring balance to the force

Comment: YAY it's at 1, i can finally downvote it!

Comment: This answer is more balanced (in terms of votes) than my life!

Comment: 101/101. There should be a medal for this.

Comment: Someone unbalanced it :/

Comment: Must be the only question which hangs in the balance. LOL

Comment: Order has been restored

Comment: ... once again.

Comment: Thanks bro. You cleared my doubts. It's just my another way to ask for upvote.

Comment: May I add that some people (like I almost did) vote faster than detecting sarcasm? [Just like this guy.](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/86/9c/54869c33dc275506f587e2c6df255f45.jpg)

Answer (score -5):

No, if someone is explicitly saying "please upvote my question" or an analogous request, then that is not alright.

On the other hand, if someone: 
(i) has a really good and useful question;
(ii) on a topic that would help a lot of people;
(iii) that is early in development, in active development, with little documentation;
(iv) mentioning that **if they thought the question was useful** an upvote would help provide more learning resources for topic;

then I believe that should be tolerated on occasion.  Especially if there are a high number of "favorites" on a question; suggesting that several people are interested in the question/answer and it's a useful resource for them.

People on YouTube ask for likes and subscriptions and obviously Stackexchange sites are vastly different and is not meant to be promoted that way.  I feel that if there is an under-represented topic that is under active development and backed by a growing community; asking the reader to acknowledge that more attention to GOOD questions on the matter will provide more resources to learn from.

"My question is, what should I do if I face this kind of scenario? Should I edit / flag / leave the question alone and enjoy my beer, etc.?" If it is blatantly self-promoting, edit out the section and the reason why it was edited in the comments.

I'm probably going to get a lot of negative feedback in the comments but it's my honest answer to a debatable topic.

Comment: There's a place for a *meta* post — i.e., discussing the site — to ask people to upvote questions more *in a given tag*. I would support that. (In fact I've considered that myself.) But asking people to upvote *this particular* question is misplaced meta and noisy self-promotion. That's not worth keeping around.

Comment: I feel that this question is biased and is not a discussion; posts that don't entirely agree with a "hard no" will be disregarded and not opened for conversation.  I understand Stackexchange is definitely not a discussion forum but since this question is subjective and opinion-based, a discussion could be appropriate for this context.

Comment: There's a difference between being *disregarded* and being *disagreed with*. Pretty sure the community is just disagreeing, here.

Comment: Does disagree = downvote? What constitutes a down-vote on a subjective question asking for an opinion?

Comment: If your answer gives an opinion about what to do that others do not think is useful or correct, it will be downvoted. This is especially true on meta, but it's true anywhere. (This is why primarily opinion-based questions are closed on main sites.) In short, a downvote says "No, I don't think so."

Comment: @o.rka on meta, downvote can mean disagreement, on top of the normal reasons. In any case.... ANYTHING not DIRECTLY related to the question at hand is noise. Even in your edge case. A question should contain info about one thing: the topic of the question.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  I have never seen nor responded to a question like this before so I wasn't sure the etiquette.

Answer (score -11):

I do think asking to upvote is simply bad etiquette.

However, just giving the poster the benefit of the doubt, maybe he/she comes from a different SX community where upvoting is much more common.  And so he/she wonders why the question doesn't receive any votes despite the fact that people engage with it.  I am new here and it took me a while to realize that even if your question has 0 votes it doesn't necessarily mean that it's not a good/clear question.  People on SO generally don't vote as often on new questions as do other communities.

So I guess it's a matter of what a vote "means".  On SO it seems that a vote (specifically the first vote of a question) means more or less something along the lines "This question is not off-topic, clearly worded/formatted, the poster tried to figure it out on their own but couldn't, and it's a good and useful question that contributes something to the community" whereas in other communities a single vote might mean simply "This question is not off-topic and it's clearly worded".

SO is a much bigger community and usually questions get answers much faster than elsewhere.  So while in other smaller communities an upvote might function as a type of encouragement to the poster, your question is fine, there's nothing wrong with it, but it might take a while till someone answers (there are simply not that many members available to answer).  This is mostly not necessary on SO since questions do get answers pretty quickly.  And getting an answer itself could be considered a kind of upvote (no one would answer a question they think is off topic or a bad question).

The fact that SO is so big of course also means that there are many members with different interpretations of what votes mean and use them differently.

Comment: This might answer "Why did this user decide to ask for upvotes?" and encourage understanding between different sorts of SO users. However, it doesn't answer "Is it OK?" - if it is not OK, that doesn't mean there is anything wrong with the OP, just that the question should be corrected to fit standards.

Comment: @NeilSlater I absolutely agree, which is why I wrote "I do think it's bad etiquette" — I guess that's an answer to the question (there's no point in repeating what others already stated).  I just wanted to add a potential explanation of such (bad) behavior to the discussion (I thought meta is precisely for these kinds of discussions).  But I must have gotten it wrong since I got three downvotes already  :(   — kind of interesting since we're discussing voting here ...

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thank you for letting me know.  I had hoped whomever downvotes would at least leave a comment, i.e., contribute to the discussion ... but, oh well.