# What does it mean if I got equal number of upvotes and downvotes on my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, upvotes

So if I get downvotes on my question, it means that my question is bad, not properly asked, off-topic, etc., and if I get upvotes on my question it means I asked a good question and it is helpful for the community.

But what if my question got equal number of downvotes and upvotes?

Does it mean the question is equally useful and not useful at the same time?

But I feel it contradicts. Please explain.

Comment: "Useful/Not Useful" is not the **only** criteria for voting...there is "lack of research effort" too. Perhaps some people thought you should have shown what you tried to debug the issue while some thought the question was still useful. Overall, downvotes indicate *something* is lacking...I have less faith in upvotes.

Comment: In a normal case, It would mean that you gained a net positive score: `+N*5-N*2 > 0` for `N > 0`

Comment: Controversial. It means your question is controversial. Simple as that.

Comment: Please also read on sympathy votes - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-using-an-up-vote-to-balance-out-a-down-vote-wrong/311408#311408

Comment: You should also understand that there are widely differing views among SO users of what makes a good question, just as there are widely differing views of what SO should be: a repository of high-quality Q&A's (the stated goal of SO) or a community of programmers helping each other out (the de facto way many people use the site). For questions which are e.g. very specific, and not likely to be of use to anyone but the asker, a vote often reflects the voter's view of this issue.

Comment: It really just means the obvious -- and equal number of people voted up and down. The votes don't exactly mean what you hypothesized; sometimes a downvote means "I'm in a bad mood" or "I don't know the answer" or "you didn't upvote my answer". Sometimes an upvote just means "I hope that you'll upvote my answer if I upvote your question".

Comment: @Hackr you mean votes for vote ? I don't feel it is good for the community !!

Comment: @mssirvi it's certainly not, but sometimes it happens. C'est la vie.

Comment: It means you're capable of restoring the balance of the universe.

Comment: To make things even more confusing, sometimes people upvote when they normally wouldn't to "reverse" downvotes that they don't necessarily think are warranted.

Comment: Incidentally, votes on Meta sites work slightly differently to how they work on the main sites: votes are also used to indicate agreement and disagreement. So a well-written Meta question may get lots of downvotes simply because people disagree with the premise of the question.

Comment: Sometimes it means [the community has a sense of humour](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323857/2263584) (only on Meta, though).

Comment: Sometimes I upvote just because I just don't agree with the downvote.

Comment: It means you actually said something useful, not just something that everybody auto-agrees upon.

Comment: @Renan that was really a great example :))

Comment: as of now, this question has 16 upvotes and 16 downvotes

Comment: The funny thing is to see the same number of upvotes/downvotes in this question. +16/-16 ([image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zUFC2.png)).

Comment: @Zanon oh, amazing. thanxs for the image.

Comment: Since this is meta and not main, it is possible that some of the downvotes were just for fun. For example, I could upvote and change this, but I prefer to see this question with a zero score :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Difficult to say without context.

In general it probably means that your question is worse than average though.

In aggregate questions receive [nearly 10 times](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/499081/ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-received) as many upvotes as downvotes (and for answers the ratio is 33:1).

So if your questions regularly buck this trend and acquire equal amounts of both that might indicate they are being unusually poorly received.

Comment: @Veedrac that's because I forked a different query and didn't notice the description field. There is no `TOP 1000` in the SQL. Description now edited.

Comment: I'm still not sure about your statistic, though. Consider that most votes are going to be from low-activity users searching for specific problems, whereas votes for new content are mostly going to be judged by the active site users, who are much more likely to downvote. Restricting to week-old posts suggests a typical upvote-downvote ratio of about ~1 on questions, a number I anecdotally think is more reasonable.

Comment: @Veedrac that's true, there is quite a difference there. One other factor is that crappy questions are more likely to be deleted than good ones (either automatically or manually) so the older questions still available in the data dump that have survived are likely to be better too.

Answer (score 16):

It probably means your question has some serious flaws, but also some redeeming features. If you can determine what the flaws are (lack of research, poor explanation, highly dubious requirements) and remove them, you should end up with more upvotes and fewer downvotes. (Especially if you can do the same thing for future questions before asking them.)

Answer (score 11):

You should note that the majority of people that reads your questions can't vote (unregistered) and there is much more people that is able to upvote (> 15 rep) than people able to downvote (> 125 rep).

For answers, a downvote is even more serious since the downvoter will lose rep and this prevents a great number of users to do so, even when they consider the answer to be wrong.

With that in mind, I feel that if you have the same number of upvotes/downvotes, it usually means that your post was not well received and you should consider trying to improve it with an edit

Answer (score -1):

When critics disagree, the artist is in accord with himself – Oscar Wilde